# How does Doctrine handle multiple requests?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Let's say I have a script which inserts rows into the database and it looks like this:

```
/* $start is some GET parameter. Any number between 0 and 9900 */

/* Select all objects with ids between $start and $start+99
and put their ids into $ids array */
$qb->select('object');
$qb->from('AppBundle:Object','object');
$qb->where("object.id >= $start");
$qb->andWhere("object.id < $start+100");
$objects = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

$ids = array();
foreach($objects AS $object) {
    $ids[] = $object->getId();
}

/* Create missing objects and insert them into database */
for($id=$start; $id<$start+100; ++$id) {
    if(in_array($id, $ids)) continue;
    /* Some calculations */
    $createdObject = new Object($id, $some, $data);
    $em->persist($createdObject);
}
$em->flush();
```

Now imagine there are no objects yet (the table is clear) and one user enters the site with start=0. The script takes like 2 seconds to complete. Before it finishes - another user enters the site with start=50.

I'm not sure what exactly would happen in such scenario, but I persume that:

1. First user enters - the $ids array is empty, the script is generating objects with id 0-99.
2. Second user enters - the $em->flush form the first entrance is not yet called, which means the $ids array is still empty (I guess?). The script is generating objects with id 50-149
3. There is a first $em->flush() call which comes from the first user entrance. It insert objects 0-99 into the database.
4. There is a second $em->flush() call which comes from the second user entrance. It tries to insert objects 50-149 into the database. It fails, because the object with id=50 already exists in the database. As a result it doesnt actually insert anything into the database.

Is that what would really happen? If so - how to prevent it and what is the best way to insert only those objects that are missing into the database?

@edit: This is just an exmaple code, but in the real script the id is actually 3 columns (x, y, z) and the object is a field on a map. The purpose of this script is that I want to have a huge map and it would take too much time to generate it all at once. So I want to generate only a little and then create the missing parts only when some user tries to access them. At some point the whole map will be created, but the process will be staggered.

Comment: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 bad practices here:

1. You sould avoid INSERT or UPDATE operations when users enter your site (because they are slow/costly), especially if it's about adding many objects to the database like in this script. It should run in some kind of cron script, independently from your website users.
2. You shouldn't assign ID's to your objects beforehand. Leave it as null and Doctrine will handle it for you. Why would you need to set ID in advance?

To answer your question - if you call $em->persist() for an object with a pre-assigned ID, and in case another object exists in the database with the same ID - INSERT won't happen. Instead, the already existing object will be UPDATED with the data from your newer object (when you call em->flush() afterwards). So instead of 2 objects (as expected), you will have only 1 in the database. So that's why I really doubt if you need to pre-assign IDs in advance. You should tell me more about the purpose of this :)

Comment: Actually, no. The `$em->persist()` will not make the `update` in DB. According to [documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#persisting-entities), `If X is a detached entity, an exception will be thrown on flush.` And if entity with equal ID already exists in DB, then this new entity will be "detached" entity from Doctrine's point of view.

Comment: In the real script the id is actually 3 columns: x, y and z, which are the coordinates of a field on a map. The purpose of this script is that I want to have a huge map and it would take too much time to generate it all at once. So I want to generate only a little and then create the missing parts only when some user tries to access them. At some point the whole map will be created, but the process will be staggered.